# ambiguity of a phrase

Tags: ambiguity

my grammar book deals with the ambiguity of phrases. I read that "EMT Helps Raccoon Bite Victim" can grammatically - in addition to the wrong meaning that the medical personell helped a raccoon bite its victim - read right, and this is in the sense of "EMT Helps Victim Bitten by Raccon" or "Raccon Bite Victim helped by EMT".
I don't understand, how this short headline can be read right in this second sense. In my opinion "bite" is only the infinitive and so it can be only read in the false sense.
And so I neither understand the obvious paraphrase "Raccoon Bite Victim helped by EMT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *bite-victim* is a person who has suffered a bite.  The headline simply omitted the hyphen. Maybe the newspaper didn't have the hyphen in that font-size :-)

So the newspaper was trusting the internal "ears" of its readers, expecting them to identify the collocation *bite victim* and parse the statement sanely.

The fact that the verb *help* can take a direct object (here, *victim*), helps.

P.S. The word "raccoon" does attract *bite* (i.e. *raccoon-bite*) which might give those "ears" some pause as they process the headline.  But most people would end up with a compound: raccoon-bite-victim.

Comment: You don't need a hyphen between *bite* and *victim* in any of these cases. The ambiguity lies between *raccoon bite* and *raccoon-bite*. So "EMT helps raccoon-bite victim" would be the proper way to deliver that headline.

Comment: Hyphens are just typographic conventions in any case; they attempt to represent a feature of the spoken language.

Comment: Typographic conventions help us read and avoid ambiguities like these, so I'm not sure I understand your dismissal of them.

Comment: Putting spaces between words is "just a typographic convention in any case", butitdoeshelpusunderstandenoughthatitwouldgenerallybeconsideredincorrectnottousethem.

Comment: I'm not dismissing it entirely, rather I'm dismissing it as *extra-linguistic*, i.e. as being but a typographic convention that attempts to represent a fact about speech. Typographic conventions change, often for non-linguistic reasons (e.g. a standards body says "this is how we want such-and-such to be punctuated").  So you will find just as many "snake bite victims" in the print universe as you will find "snake-bite victims".  But in the spoken universe, you will *hear* "snakebitevictims", that is, the parsing rhythms join those three words into a "german-style" compound.

Comment: No, that's not true. Any speaker can differentiate between the two by saying either "snakebite victim" or "snake bite victim": the hyphen binds "snake" and "bite" together into a single noun. In fact, you could leave it out if you joined the words together as I just typed them.

Comment: Yes it is true :-)So we will have to peaceably agree to disagree on that until someone points to a study of parsing rhythms of such phrases. My position: the brief pauses between *snake* and *bite* and *victim* are of equal duration; that is, the pause between *snake* and *bite* is not markedly briefer than that between *bite* and *victim* in such combinations.

Comment: Then why, if you disdain typographical conventions, did you put in two hyphens?

Comment: You are reading things into my statements that are not there. I don't *disdain* typographic conventions; I use them, especially the em-dash, which is divinely inspired. I just happen to regard the dots and dashes and squiggles as extra-linguistic.

Comment: If that is the case, then perhaps you could choose to be less ambiguous. Otherwise you invite people to read things into your statements.

Answer (score 2):

> And so I neither understand the obvious paraphrase "Raccoon Bite Victim helped by EMT".

Well:

> bite

Noun; an act of biting.

> Raccoon bite.

The noun *raccoon* is used to modify the noun *bite* to mean an act of biting done by a raccoon.

> Victim

Someone who has suffered something.

> bite victim

The noun *victim* is used to modify the noun *victim* to mean that the thing they suffered was a bite.

> Raccoon bite victim.

Both of these acting together to indicate that the thing the victim suffered was a bite from a raccoon.

> A raccoon bite victim was helped by an EMT.

Someone who had suffered a raccoon bite was helped by an EMT.

> Raccoon Bite Victim Helped By EMT

The same with headline-style elision.

> An EMT helped a raccoon bite victim.

The same thing, an EMT helped someone who had suffered a raccoon bite.

> EMT Helps Raccoon Bite Victim

The same again with headline-style elision.

> An EMT helped a racoon to bite its victim.

A sentence clearly stating the other interpretation.

> EMT Helps Raccoon Bite Victim

Headline-style elision results in the same phrase.

> An EMT helped a raccoon-bite victim.

Hyphens between two-word modifiers like this are optional in English orthography.

> EMT Helps Raccoon-Bite Victim

No ambiguity, which shows the value of the optional hyphen. There are times when such hyphens remove ambiguity even without headline-style elision.

Comment: +1 You got to the core of the ambiguity and how "typographical conventions" help eliminate that kind of confusion.

Comment: But if someone were reading the paper aloud (or a text-to-speech program were in use), unless the reader said "hyphen", the phrase would not have been disambiguated typographically. Sanity aside, the greater disambiguating force here is the language itself (i.e. the collocation "bite victim") not the punctuation.

Comment: @TRomano so what?

Comment: @Jon Hanna: You and Robusto are seeking for ways to *prevent* the ambiguity typographically. I am taking a different tack, and trying to get at the ways a "native ear" would *resolve* any ambiguity linguistically.  The linguistic handles both domains, text and speech.